# Why won't my companion follow me into Nightcaller Temple?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

It seems a little weird, but maybe I'm missing something.

Lydia is my current companion and won't "naturally" follow me into the temple. I went back outside to check, and yep -- she's standing right by the door.

I have tried to help her to enter by issuing a direct command but she tells me can't. (I haven't tested whether this works in general, though.)

Is this a glitch or a gameplay element -- maybe the 'arcane/evil' factor of the place combined with my 'unmagic' follower or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nightcaller Temple is related to a specific quest, Walking Nightmare. On that quest, you accompany a specific person, Erandur, into the Temple, and in doing so, wouldn't be able to take another companion along with you.

I'm not sure if it's a bug that your follower can't accompany you into the temple if you're not on that quest, or if that's by design.

[Source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Waking_Nightmare)

Comment: It won't be bugged if you use cheats to let your follower inside, he/she will just go back inside. Same thing with the  old Dark Brotherhood sanctuary.